# Newline in sink output data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Why does azure data factory data flow automatically add new line to the output file? Can this be deleted or is there a settings to configure? See the screenshot of the first image.

[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdzMR.png)

I have only 1 row/record when I preview the data.

[sink data preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm8xC.png)

Sorry, I have to removed/blurred the data.

Comment: I am not able to see the new line you are talking about. Can you share more details ? Source and Sink dataset type ? Also snips of inspect tab

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this scenario and you are right. This happens in some file types. Such as I see in .CSV and binary files.

I know that when using Binary dataset, ADF does not parse file content but treat it as-is, and you can only copy from Binary dataset to Binary dataset.

And Data Preview is a snapshot of your transformed data using row limits and data sampling from data frames in Spark memory. Therefore, the sink drivers are not utilized or tested in this scenario. It shows limited number of rows when previewed and the number of columns shown in preview is adopted from the first row in the file.

I can see it as below:

[image]

Output file from sink in ADF preview editor in Storage container:

[image]

[image]

You can also confirm by looking at the inspect tab

[image]

I also tried downloading the output file to local and opening using different editors to confirm the behavior (New line '16' got appended automatically)

[image]

**Workaround:** You can try use DelimitedText as source dataset or Json as sink dataset instead.

Please share your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-azure-data-factory) with product group so that they can look into this.

Similar Feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/40268644--preview-file-in-blob-container-vs-edit